# Package performs differently on two different instances on the same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm investigating some performance issues for our BI team.  They have a package which runs extremely slow and will sometimes run indefinitely on one instance but finishes normally on another instance.  Both instances reside on the same server and both are using the same package.  I've tried collecting PerfMon counters which show Page Life Expectency well bellow 300 and eventually reaching 0.

I'm also seeing ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait types when I use Activity Monitor to see what is occurring.  The ASYNC_NETWORK_IO occurs when it tries to execute a stored proc which I've scripted out and am able to run to completion in under 30 seconds.

I'm not quite sure where I should look for what is causing the Page Life Expectency to be so low or if I should be tracking down the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits.

These instances are running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a W2K8 R2 VM with 32 GB of ram.

What is the ideal troubleshooting path for two instances on the same server performing differently?

Comment: Are the configurations identical on both VMs? PLE dropping to zero indicates that memory pressure may be an issue as pages that are in memory are being flushed and not staying there.

Comment: Could blocking be an issue?

Comment: Sounds like it could be. ASYNC_NETWORK_IO means that SQL server is waiting for an application to pick up what it's placed in the output buffer and for the application to send acknowledgement back to SQL.  That in and of itself could cause blocking.

Comment: Is your package accesses data outside the box? It could be network issue. But most likely your package accesses a lot of rows in batch and can not utilize them fast. So the SQL Server waits for SSIS to read the actual recordset. This could be connected to available resources like CPU, memory or IO. How do you configure memory for both instances? I would check memory consumption on the server, using "Memory - Available bytes" and "Paging File % usage". I would also check what is going on at the time your package is running with sp_whoisactive or use dmv sys.dm_exec_requests, sys.dm_exec_session

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer: Both instances are on the same VM.  I'm unsure what the application would be that is causing the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO since we are doing everything within SQL Server itself.

Comment: Is maximum server memory configured on both instances?  If not, both instances may be fighting over the same memory pool and causing pages to flush out of memory and not stay put. If you are going to have 2 instances on the same machine, you have to limit how much memory each instance can use.  Can I ask why they are both on the same VM?

Comment: The "Memory - Available bytes" fluxuates between 5GB and 7GB.  I haven't looked at Paging File % yet.  I will also start looking at sp_whoisactive and the other dmv's you suggested.

Comment: Both instances have their max memory set to 6 GB.  This is for our development environment so I'm assuming that's why they are on the same VM.  I've only been with the company for about a month so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe you're waiting on the data to land in the destination table. Perhaps there is activity going on which is keeping the package from locking the target table. They could also be doing lots of dumb things so try posting a screenshot of the Control Flow and your data flows. Between the destination and the penultimate component, double click on the connector line and get a screenshot of your MetaData tab. Finally, double click the destination and give us a peek into that. Punch all that into the question if you would

Comment: Hi its difficult to find correlation between Async Network_IO and PLE. Only thing that comes in my mind is client is fetching huge data from Server and doing filtering on client side. Can you try limiting the result set fetched. Does SQL Server errorlog has any unusual information. Check network between server and client as well

Comment: ASYNC_NETWORK_IO can be seen just by use of SSMS constantly by your development team. That could also be coming from using Activity Monitor within SSMS. Bookmark this [wait stats script from Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) and use it to determine what the instances are actually waiting on overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this issue was due to a restore of a database from an incorrect media set.  Since the databases were not exact copies, the package was performing differently on the second instance.  After performing a backup with INIT and then restoring that database to the second instance, the package now performs the same on both instances.